# How to merge two or more list uniquely in c#

Tags: c#, list

I have three list in which some of items are common. I want to merge all them to form one new list as per following conditions:

1. All items in new list must be unique.
2. If any item is available two or more (three) lists, the order of that item should be as such that all items before that item of every list must be added before that item in new list.
3. Uncommon items may be added in any order but subject to point no. 2.

For demonstration:

```
    List1:
    D
    B
    C
    K
    R
    
    List2:
    D
    A
    B
    G
    C
    K
    T
    R
    
    List3:
    D
    B
    C
    K
    M
    R
```

Desired Output

```
New List:
    D
    A
    B
    G
    C
    K
    T
    M
    R
```

I've tried **union** but it does not give desired (order) output.

Comment: is this school work or what? and what have you tried?

Comment: (2) isn't adequately described.  What if my three lists are `A B C` `C B A` and `C A  B`? All letters should be before all other letters based on requirement (2)

Comment: @MoHo This will not be happen. Order of occurrence will same in all list. If "B" comes before "A" in any list, it will comes before "A" in all list. Please look at my demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make a call to .Distinct() which will return only the unique elements of a list.

Basic usage:

```cs
var list1 = new List<char> {
    'D',
    'A',
    'B',
    'G',
    'C',
    'K',
    'T',
    'R'
};
        
var list2 = new List<char> {
    'D',
    'B',
    'C',
    'K',
    'M',
    'R'
};

var combined = list1.Concat(list2);

Dictionary<char,int> occurances = new Dictionary<char,int>();

foreach(var letter in combined){
    if(occurances.ContainsKey(letter)){
        // The letter is already in, so we give it +1 occurance
        occurances[letter] += 1;
    }else{
        // New letter, add it with 1 occurance
        occurances.Add(letter, 1);
    }
}

var sortedItems = occurances
    .OrderByDescending(o=>o.Value) // Using descending order so we get 3...2...1... etc.
    .Select(s=>s.Key) // Select the key (the character)
    .Distinct(); // Use distinct to eliminate the duplicates
```

Here is a [.NET Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UgS5cE)

Comment: Thanks, but you missed condition on point no 2 which is most important.

Comment: Sorry I missed that at first. Your wording on the 2nd point is a little confusing. I've updated the fiddle and my answer which shows one way to get the items sorted from most to least occurrences.

Comment: Sorry, I can't elaborate properly. I want to insert "B" in new list only after "D" and "A" because in List2, "B" comes after "D" & "A" whereas it comes after "D" in List1 & List3. Likewise "R" must be inserted at last in new list.